# Techniques for reversing (basic) hash function

Tags: radare2, gdb, hash-functions

Hi I'm relatively new to RE, and I'm using GDB and Radare2. As part of a crackme I'm trying to reverse a weak hash function that's a little too complicated for me to undo by hand. I've been trying to execute backwards with GDB but no luck. What are the common techniques for accomplishing this task?

Comment: What is the hash function, specifically? Depends on the specific properties (small output/linear/etc.) there may be some specific ways to do it (brute force/solve linear equations)

Comment: Best I can tell it just takes a numerical input and sequentially adds/subtracts numbers with it and xor's it with several values, looping this several times. It's not a "real" hash function, so in principle I could by undo all these operations by hand. But there are so many in series it would be impractical.

Comment: I think you should still post the code, advices would be too general. For now -- "the composition of many easily reversible functions is also easily reversible".